# App Transport Security (ATT) shown only once on iOS 17

Tags: ios, swift, app-transport-security

I'm not able to pass App Store review because ATT dialog is shown only once.

Starting from iOS 17 the ATT dialog is only shown the first time the app is installed.

After that, even after deleting the app, reinstalling it results in the ATT permission being already determined.

In contrast, on iOS 16, each time I delete and reinstall the app, the ATT permission question appears as expected.

I conducted similar tests with various apps from the App Store developed by different individuals, and the behavior on iOS 17 remains consistent. I don't know how they passed App Store Review.

Any idea how to solve this?